# Custom font issue in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

**Requirement:** I need to apply custom font.

**Brief explanation:** In `app.scss` we are calling fonts shown below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

    // @font-face {
//   font-family: 'Humanst';
//   src: url('../assets/fonts/humanst-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../assets/fonts/humanst-webfont.woff') format('woff');
//   font-weight: normal;
//   font-style: normal;
// }

// * {
//   font-family: 'Humanst' !important;
// }
```

When we do `ionic serve`, this font is not applied, problem doesn't end here, if we comment the **Roboto font** code and uncomment **Humanst**, menu icon, back icon, and all other icons also disappear [see top left and top right] as shown in image below.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: You can do the same process described to use font awsome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `variables.scss` & add the following code at the end of the file:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Humanst';
   src: url('../assets/fonts/humanst-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../assets/fonts/humanst-webfont.woff') format('woff');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
 }

$font-family-base: 'Humanst';
$font-family-ios-base: 'Humanst';
$font-family-md-base: 'Humanst';
$font-family-wp-base: 'Humanst';
```

**!important**
should only be used as a last resort otherwise it will override everything!